# Custom Post By Category

Tags: custom-post-types, php, posts, wp-query, categories

I want to achieve a specific functionality in WordPress 
[image]

How to achieve this functionality where the post(heading and content) coming from the recent news post category and the progress bar with fundraising and goals are listed below of every post. The whole post is on a carousel slider. Can anyone just give me the idea? Or any other plugin suggests achieving that functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately, plugin recommendations are considered off-topic here - and your question may otherwise be too broad to provide a definitive answer. Please review the "[ask]" page in our [help]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can find a plugin which supports this type of functionality, you have to write your own plugin.

- find a slider which supports HTML divs inside it.
- for goal and the raised amount, you can save them in the custom post type.
- for the progress bar, you can use [this](https://www.w3schools.com/Bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_progressbar2&stacked=h) one, this will prevent you to load unnecessary js on load

  ```
  <? $args = array(
  'post_type'=> 'services',
  'areas'    => 'painting',
  'order'    => 'ASC'
  );

  $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
  if($the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : 
  $the_query->the_post(); ?>
  ```

Comment: I have used your code it works but it showing same post item 3times on each data slide

Comment: i know its bit late but might be your slider image is not in loop